# Crystal Reports login error

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created a report via crystal report. It works on my pc. Database field is null . But when I tried to run on another pc then a window opens. The window has 4 textbox (2 readonly 2 editable)

```
Server*     192.168.1.2
Database* 
UserName   myusername  +
Password   mypassword  +
```

(*) places are read only and + places are editable. But i can't change database name . I think the problem is it but i can't understand how can I solve this. I haven't got any problem on my pc. Problem is only on other computers. I setted up crystal reports runtime editions on these computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Datasource settings on your report. Not sure how you are setting those in your code.
Refer these links that display how to set it:

```
// Create a new customer orders report.
CustomerOrdersReport report = new CustomerOrdersReport();

// Get the report data.
DataTable customersTable = getCustomersData();
DataTable ordersTable = getOrdersData();

// Set datasources.
report.Database.Tables["Customers"].SetDataSource(customersTable);
report.Database.Tables["Orders"].SetDataSource(ordersTable ); // Don't forget this line like I did!!
```

There are other examples available:

[Web Crystal reports produce Database logon failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867678/web-crystal-reports-produce-database-logon-failed)

[[Failed in Production]](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.crystal-reports/database-logon-failed-in-production-s/83732)

If you still have a problem, post your code of how you are setting datasource for your report.